# How to COUNT DISTINCT on basis of Selective columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, row, distinct

I have a table in SQL Server containing 7 columns as:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | Source_Node | Source_Node_Type | Target_Node | Target_Node_Type | Year | Edge_Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1    10965          2                  23036        3                  2005   2
2    10965          2                  23036        3                  2005   2
3    2947           2                  23036        3                  2005   2
4    37529          4                  23036        3                  2005   4
...  
...
```

Whereas I have to COUNT DISTINCT rows on basis of only two columns i.e. `Source_Node` and `Target_Node` e.g. rows with `id` 1 and 2 have same values for `Source_Node` and `Target_Node`, so these should be get COUNT only once. I have tried query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GraphEdges
WHERE Source_Node IN (...Node_List...) 
AND Target_Node IN (...Node_List)
```

It gives COUNT of 58 whereas on trying this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node, Target_Node FROM GraphEdges
WHERE Source_Node IN (...Node_List...) 
AND Target_Node IN (...Node_List...)
```

It gives 53 rows, the figure I need but it gives the whole rows whereas I need the COUNT figure i.e. 53.
How can I modify query?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried `Group by` command?

Comment: @ No I need only COUNT figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it with another select like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Source_Node, Target_Node FROM GraphEdges
    WHERE Source_Node IN (...Node_List...) 
           AND Target_Node IN (...Node_List...))
```

Or a solution without a subquery :

```
SELECT count(distinct concat(Source_Node,Target_Node))
FROM GraphEdges
WHERE Source_Node IN (...Node_List...) 
      AND Target_Node IN (...Node_List...))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to group by your sourcenode and target node. then count the grouped rows.

```
select count(*) from
(select Source_Node_Type, Target_Node_Type from GraphEdges group by Source_Node_Type, Target_Node_Type) a
```